# Ruby on rails, reading and showing csv-file doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I am implementing in Ruby on Rails and I just want something easy to do, i just want to read a csv file and then show the output in a view. I have some code which seems good to me, but i always get the errror : can't convert Tempfile into String
This is my controller:

```
def match
file = params[:file]

@original_filename = file.original_filename
tmpfile = Tempfile.new("redmine_project_importer")
if tmpfile
    tmpfile.write(file.read)
    tmpfile.close
    tmpfilename = File.basename(tmpfile.path)
      if !$tmpfiles
        $tmpfiles = Hash.new
      end
      $tmpfiles[tmpfilename] = tmpfile
    else
      flash[:error] = "Cannot save import file."
      return
    end
 session[:importer_tmpfile] = tmpfilename
sample_count = 5
i = 0
@samples = []
FasterCSV.open(file, "r") do |row|       
        @samples[i] = row
        i += 1
        if i > sample_count
            break
        end
    end
```

and my view is just:

```
<% form_tag({:action => 'result'}, {:multipart => true}) do %>
<table>  

<% @samples.each do |sample| %>
  <tr>
     <td>sample</td>    
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Someone who can help me out?
Greetz

Answer (score 1):

1) `FasterCSV.open()` requires a String filename, and you're passing a File object to it.

2) It's `FasterCSV.foreach(filename)` if you want to iterate lines. Or `FasterCSV.open().each`

But in your case, if you have an uploaded File parameter, you're better off with

```
FasterCSV.new(params[:file]).each do |line|
```

et cetera

Comment: I've done this, I do not have an error anymore. But i still don't have any output. Just like @samples is empty, how come this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with FasterCSV, but I think you should give Spreadsheet a look - http://spreadsheet.ch/

You should be able to read a csv file as simply as this:

```
book = Spreadsheet.open path_to_file
sheet  = book.worksheet 0
```

You could then iterate through the rows and perform whatever action you want:

```
sheet.each do |row|
  #code
end
```